# Is there a good "OCaml Browser" tool for Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, emacs, ocaml, typerex

I'm using Emacs + Typerex for OCaml programming. I have tried OcaIDE before in Windows. It's not as nice as Typerex, but it does have a good feature: Ocaml Browser

[image: OcaIDE in Windows]

Is there anyway to have such a browser in Typerex? 
(eclipse + OcaIDE in linux might work, but I do not like it as much as typerex)

Thanks

Comment: You also have some browsing commands with typerex, like goto-definition, grep, etc... More on this [link](http://www.typerex.org/manual-ide.html#browsing)

Comment: @didierc. Oh Yes I just found that I can launch that browser in a shell. Thanks. I'd like that built-in to typerex, but I guess I'm asking too much.

Comment: @cago I have tried that but it does not work nicely. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ocamlbrowser` is actually the name of a program that has been distributed with the OCaml compiler for a very long time. It is written with LablTk, maintained by Jacques Garrigue, and was inside the "ocaml distribution" (instead of an external tool) because it accessed `.cmi` files in ways that rely on internal details of the compiler.

So the short answer is: "yes, just call `ocamlbrowser` in your terminal" (assuming your distribution packaged ocamlbrowser with the compiler, which may or may not be the case; there may be a separate ocamlbrowser package instead). The look&feel of the tool may be a bit dated compared to a shiny Eclipse version, but it indeed exists and works fine.